# Indie movie about alien abduction on popcorn time, guy wakes up in a hospital with super strength, eventually realizes he's on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, soft-sci-fi

A guy wakes up at a place similar to an hospital and begins to run away from there. Seems to be on Earth and he's being chased. At some point he realizes he has super strength, like an orange glow comes out from his arms. At the end he realizes he's not on Earth, he's on a spaceship that imitates Earth.

Comment: What does Popcorn Time have to do with the question?

Comment: I think it's The Signal (2014)

Comment: Yes! The signal!

Comment: @Vahn you should post that as an answer so that you, Victor, can accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

Per Vahn's suggestion and the OP's confirmation in comments, this was *[The Signal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2910814)* (2014).

According to [Wikipedia's plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Signal_(2014_film)) for the film:

> Nic, now with the number 2.3.5.41 tattooed on his arm, **wakes up in a
>   strange and sterile underground research facility** where he is
>   questioned by Dr. Wallace Damon, the head of the "transition group" in
>   charge of helping Nic to cope with his strange situation...
>
> Jonah reveals that he too had limbs taken from him, as
>   his **forearms and hands have been replaced with the same alien
>   technology as Nic's legs**. Jonah speculates that they are in Area 51
>   and that this is all a test...

At the end:

> Nic finds himself inside what appears to be a different facility
>   behind a projected image of the outside world beyond the canyon.
>   Turning back toward the bridge, he sees Damon remove his helmet to
>   reveal that he is actually a robotic alien. Nic walks towards a window
>   and **realizes he is not in a facility, but is on an immense alien
>   spacecraft** numbered 2.3.5.41 (matching the numerical tattoo on his
>   arm) that is about to dock at their home-world...